# How to get all animations of FBX file in Unity for arbitrary FBX model?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, augmented-reality, game-development, fbx

I am very new to development in general and to Unity and augmented reality, particularly.

Let's suppose, that I have an AR app, in which I can upload and see my models in the real world. The problem is that the app can't play animations, because it is not getting the `animation data` from models (which are in `FBX` format). I have managed to search how to get, for example, names or meshes from `fbx`, but I don't have a clue how to get the animation data.

I need some way that will work for any arbitrary model. Any ideas on how can I start or how to resolve the situation?

Comment: Look into Animation Controllers

Comment: @slaphshot33324 Thanks for the comment. i have created animation controller, but i am confused. should i add animations to it manually? the key is that i want to get the job done only in editor, by a script